# Gradle - Publish artifact to github

Tags: java, gradle

I'm having some trouble to publish artifact to github in gradle project. I have already created a github repository. I did this in maven using maven-deploy-plugin and its completely straight forward. Here is the pluging configuration.

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <altDeploymentRepository>internal.repo::default::file://${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</altDeploymentRepository>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
                <artifactId>site-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.11</version>
                <configuration>
                    <message>Maven artifacts for ${project.version}</message>  <!-- git commit message -->
                    <noJekyll>true</noJekyll>                                  <!-- disable webpage processing -->
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</outputDirectory> <!-- matches distribution management repository url above -->
                    <branch>refs/heads/master</branch>                       <!-- remote branch name -->
                    <includes><include>**/*</include></includes>
                    <repositoryName>{git_repo_name}</repositoryName>      <!-- github repo name -->
                    <repositoryOwner>{git_user_name}</repositoryOwner>    <!-- github username  -->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!-- run site-maven-plugin's 'site' target as part of the build's normal 'deploy' phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>site</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

But my question is how can I do this in gradle ?

Answer (score 1):

The beauty and curse of gradle is the flexibility. Google search shows 3 promising plugins:

- https://github.com/riiid/gradle-github-plugin
- https://github.com/trnl/github-release-gradle-plugin
- https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git/wiki

Perhaps one of them solves your problem. Let me know if you are looking for something specific.